# Using LINQ to perform a LEFT OUTER JOIN in 2 DataTables (Multiples criteria)

Tags: c#, performance, linq, .net-datatable, join

I know that exists a lot of solutions about how to create an `OUTER JOIN` between two `DataTables`.

I created the following code in C#:

```
DataTable vDT1 = new DataTable();
vDT1.Columns.Add("Key");
vDT1.Columns.Add("Key2");
vDT1.Columns.Add("Data1");
vDT1.Columns.Add("Data2");

vDT1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA1_AAAA", "DATA2_AAAA" });
vDT1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "02", "ZZ", "DATA1_BBBB", "DATA2_BBBB" });

DataTable vDT2 = new DataTable();
vDT2.Columns.Add("Key");
vDT2.Columns.Add("Key2");
vDT2.Columns.Add("Data3");
vDT2.Columns.Add("Data4");

vDT2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA3_AAAA", "DATA4_AAAA" });
vDT2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA3_BBBB", "DATA4_BBBB" });
vDT2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA3_CCCC", "DATA4_CCCC" });
vDT2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA3_DDDD", "DATA4_DDDD" });

DataTable vDT3 = new DataTable();
vDT3.Columns.Add("Key");
vDT3.Columns.Add("Key2");
vDT3.Columns.Add("Data1");
vDT3.Columns.Add("Data2");
vDT3.Columns.Add("KeyTemp1");
vDT3.Columns.Add("KeyTemp2");
vDT3.Columns.Add("Data3");
vDT3.Columns.Add("Data4");

DataRow vDRnull = vDT2.Rows.Add();

var vLINQ = vDT1.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupJoin(vDT2.AsEnumerable(), 
        dr1 => new { key1 = dr1["Key"], key2 = dr1["Key2"] }, 
        dr2 => new { key1 = dr2["Key"], key2 = dr2["Key2"] },
        (dr1, result) => dr1.ItemArray.Koncat(
            ((result.FirstOrDefault<DataRow>() == null) 
                ? vDRnull 
                : result.FirstOrDefault<DataRow>()).ItemArray));

foreach (var aw in vLINQ)
{
    vDT3.Rows.Add(aw);
}
```

I implemented this extension:

```
public static T[] Koncat<T>(this T[] x, T[] y)
{
    if (x == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("x");
    if (y == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("y");
    int oldLen = x.Length;
    Array.Resize<T>(ref x, x.Length + y.Length);
    Array.Copy(y, 0, x, oldLen, y.Length);
    return x;
}
```

[image: result]

This easy and clean (from my point of view), but I wanted to ask the experts for recommendations, improvements, or if this method have a performance flaw.

Normally I need manage huge amount of data (More than 100K items).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DataTable`s are quite powefull and offer lots of the real database functionality. Also as far as joins are concerned a few things are possible and I'm of the opinion that if someone uses `DataTable`s he also should use the functionality they offer ;-)

It this case using `DataTable` joins your example could look like this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("Key");
dt1.Columns.Add("Key2");
dt1.Columns.Add("Data1");
dt1.Columns.Add("Data2");

dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA1_AAAA", "DATA2_AAAA" });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "02", "ZZ", "DATA1_BBBB", "DATA2_BBBB" });

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("Key");
dt2.Columns.Add("Key2");
dt2.Columns.Add("Data3");
dt2.Columns.Add("Data4");

dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA3_AAAA", "DATA4_AAAA" });
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA3_BBBB", "DATA4_BBBB" });
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA3_CCCC", "DATA4_CCCC" });
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA3_DDDD", "DATA4_DDDD" });
//dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "02", "ZZ", "DATA5_DDDD", "DATA4_DDDD" });

ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
ds.Tables.Add(dt2);

// specify the relations between the data tables
DataRelation drel = new DataRelation(
    "MyJoin",
    new DataColumn[] { dt1.Columns["Key"], dt1.Columns["Key2"] },
    new DataColumn[] { dt2.Columns["Key"], dt2.Columns["Key2"]});

ds.Relations.Add(drel);

DataTable jt = new DataTable("JoinedTable");
jt.Columns.Add("Key");
jt.Columns.Add("Key2");
jt.Columns.Add("Data1");
jt.Columns.Add("Data2");
jt.Columns.Add("Data3");
jt.Columns.Add("Data4");
ds.Tables.Add(jt);

// create the result table
foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{
    var childRows = row.GetChildRows("MyJoin");
    // mimics left join
    var hasChildRows = childRows.Length > 0;
    if (!hasChildRows) 
    {
        jt.Rows.Add(row["Key"], row["Key2"], row["Data1"], row["Data2"], null, null);
        continue;
    }

    foreach (var child in childRows)
    {
        jt.Rows.Add(row["Key"], row["Key2"], row["Data1"], row["Data2"], child["Data3"], child["Data4"]);
    }
}

jt.Rows.Dump(); // LINQPad dump
```

[image: Result DataTable]

---

As far as your code is concerned I'm not happy with the `Koncat` method because it modifies the `ItemArray` that belongs to the `DataRow` instead of creating a new result.

You actually don't need it because `LINQ` already has a such a method that you could use like this:

```
dr1.ItemArray
.Concat(result.Any() ? result.First().ItemArray: Enumerable.Empty<object>())
.ToArray());
```

It's not necessary to call the `FirstOrDefault` method two times. It's better to just check if the result has `Any` rows and then get the `First` one and its `ItemArray` or otherwise an empty `IEnumerable`, finally you turn it into an array and you're done:

```
var vLINQ = vDT1.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupJoin(
        vDT2.AsEnumerable(), 
        dr1 => new { key1 = dr1["Key"], key2 = dr1["Key2"] }, 
        dr2 => new { key1 = dr2["Key"], key2 = dr2["Key2"] },
        (dr1, result) => 
            dr1.ItemArray
            .Concat(result.Any() ? result.First().ItemArray: Enumerable.Empty<object>())
            .ToArray());
```

or if you can use `C# 6` even shorter with the `?.` and `??` operators

```
dr1.ItemArray
.Concat(result.FirstOrDefault()?.ItemArray ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>())
.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips and corrections! I fixed my code; seems that runs faster.